How to divide large numbers by small numbers without rounding in Python
Using Python 3, I want to calculate 18446744073709550592 / 65536. In Python I get the output:
281474976710656

But the actual result is:
281474976710655.984375

It is automatically rounded? Is there any way to calculate it accurately?
In the case of larger numbers, for example:
101145323450295648841204270695912834609459452764473586182335661131099020400596942132578006286870917941163064976533634484749130329189561344995256870 / 65536, Python gives output:
1.543355155186396e+141

The expect result:
1543355155186396008929508525023084024192191356879784945409174516770920111093092989083526707258162200029953994392908241039262852923424703140186.4146423339


Hrm, 18446744073709550592 is 2^64 - 1024. You wouldn’t be trying to do bitwise arithmetic using float division would you? The second large number is the header of an mp4 file, when stored as a big-endian integer. Similarly: float division would not be the ideal way to deal with such bytestrings/integers.

@nneoneo Do you have a better way to handle it?

Well, what are you trying to do? Usually, the way to handle bitstrings would be to use bit shifts and masking (<<, &). But if you're interested in 16-bit units, maybe you want to use the struct module to read structured binary data. It all depends on what you're aiming to do.


use python's decimal module to avoid rounding errors.

from decimal import Decimal

numerator = Decimal('18446744073709550592')
denominator = Decimal('65536')
result = numerator / denominator
print(result)


To get fraction for very larger numbers, use the following code:
first perform integer division to get quotient.
Then perform modulo for remainder.
Convert the remainder into decimal by dividing it.
Then manually construct the decimal part as a string.

numerator = 101145323450295648841204270695912834609459452764473586182335661131099020400596942132578006286870917941163064976533634484749130329189561344995256870

denominator = 65536
quotient = numerator // denominator
remainder = numerator % denominator

fraction_part = f"{remainder * 10**30 // denominator}".rjust(30, '0')
result = f"{quotient}.{fraction_part}"
print(result)


With larger number as: 101145323450295648841204270695912834609459452764473586182335661131099020400596942132578006286870917941163064976533634484749130329189561344995256870 / 65536, Decimal module can't resolve.

@QChíNguyễn add from decimal import getcontext and getcontext().prec = 153 (or any other precision you want). It then gives the exact expected output.

If your numerators could be arbitrarily large, one solution is to examine the quotient and remainder separately; these will correspond to the whole number and fractional parts of the full division result respectively.
For example:
quo, rem = divmod(18446744073709550592, 65536)
print(quo)
print(rem / 65536)

This prints 281474976710655 and 0.984375 corresponding to the whole and fractional parts of the division result.
If you need arbitrary precision in the fractional part, you can use the decimal module as indicated in other answers. However, this solution will preserve the full precision of the whole part without needing to manually adjust the decimal precision.

The only "accurate" result for all numbers will be a rational fraction (think, e.g., 1/3). You can find this by first subtracting the remainder (obtainable by the modulus operation), then doing integer division (use the // operator).
Optionally, you can reduce the resulting fraction by the greatest common divisor (aka "highest common factor").
BTW, what are you planning to do with these staggeringly large numbers?
import math

def divide( top, bottom ):
    remainder = top % bottom                     # remainder will yield the fractional part
    quotient = ( top - remainder ) // bottom     # should be amenable to exact integer division
    return quotient, remainder

a, b = 18446744073709550592, 65536
q, r = divide( a, b )
if r == 0: 
   print( q )
else: 
   g = math.gcd( r, b );   r //= g;   b //= g;  # use if you want to reduce the fraction to smallest form
   print( f"{q} {r}/{b}" )                      # the only "accurate" result will be a rational fraction

Output:
281474976710655 63/64


In Python, integers are arbitrary precision, means they can hold extremely large values without rounding or losing precision. However, when dividing integers, the result is converted to a floating-point number, which has limited precision and can cause rounding.
To calculate division accurately without floating-point rounding, perform exact division using fractions.
1.
from fractions import Fraction

result = Fraction(18446744073709550592, 65536)
print(result)  
print(float(result))  
2.
from fractions import Fraction

large_number = Fraction(101145323450295648841204270695912834609459452764473586182335661131099020400596942132578006286870917941163064976533634484749130329189561344995256870, 65536)
print(large_number) 

For larger output, convert the fraction to a string:
print(str(large_number))

